# ui-scroll two table using the same datasource and scrolling in sync of both tables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angular-ui, ui-scroll

I am using [ui-scroll](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll) in my application and ran into some issues.

I want to run ui-scroll on same datasource used to build two tables and by scrolling one table it should also scroll the other table which is created via same datasource.

I have tried to achieve that using following sample code but it doesn't work.

When scrolling any of the tables the behaviour of the lists is weird; it increases the size of the list and empty rows are shows. It can noticed in the plunker attached.

And if I change the data it only affects to the first table and the second one doesn't update the list.

Also I can not make the sync (sorry for the stupid question, if anyone can help).

Here is how I am doing:

**Template:**

```
<table border="1"> 
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <table> 
        <tbody id="first-tbody" ui-scroll-viewport style="height: 400px">
          <tr ui-scroll="item in datasource" adapter="adapter" start-index="0">
            <td>{{item}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td> 
      <table>
        <tbody id="second-tbody" ui-scroll-viewport style="height: 400px">
          <tr ui-scroll="item in datasource" adapter="adapter2" start-index="0">
            <td>{{item}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller:**

```
var datasource = {};
datasource.get = function (index, count, success) {
    $timeout(function () {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = index; i <= index + count - 1; i++) {
            result.push("item #" + i);
        }
        success(result);
    }, 100);
};
$scope.datasource = datasource;
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/CBPDlqx5P6Rc4tPZzGaw?p=preview

Any help would be highly appreciated. TIA

When scrolling too fast the first and last rows which ui-scroll adds for some scrolling calculations tend to have larger than 100px height. How to tackle them? Can i just hide them?

Here is the picture showing how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is not ok with display css-property in these template and it seems a good idea to extract both viewports into separate div-containers... The following code fixes empty rows issue:

```
<table border="1"> 
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <div ui-scroll-viewport style="height: 400px;">
        <table> 
          <tbody id="first-tbody" >
            <tr ui-scroll="item in datasource" adapter="adapter" start-index="0">
              <td>{{item}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td> 
      <div ui-scroll-viewport style="height: 400px;">
        <table>
          <tbody id="second-tbody" >
            <tr ui-scroll="item in datasource" adapter="adapter2" start-index="0">
              <td>{{item}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The updated demo is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/JjAiw3zvG4uIWGNjLUU7

---

Regarding 2 viewports scroll syncing, I guess, following approach might work:

```
$scope.datasource = {};
$scope.datasource.get = function (index, count, success) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = index; i <= index + count - 1; i++) {
        result.push("item #" + i);
    }
    success(result); 
};

const vp1 = document.getElementById('vp1');
const vp2 = document.getElementById('vp2');
vp1.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    vp2.scrollTop = vp1.scrollTop;
});
```

where "vp1" and "vp2" are ids of the viewports.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but how to resolve the syncing issue? How can i make the scrolling of both tables in sync in addition to using ui scroll.

Comment: Wow thank you :) I have implement your solution and it works great but there is small problem still with the ui-scroll. If i scroll too fast the empty rows at the start and end which ui-scroll adds tend to have larger than 100px height. I have added picture to my original question for reference. Sorry asking repeatedly for issues.

Comment: @arsinawaz These padding elements are under scroller internal control and in general can't be maintained outside run-time. Looks like you have inconsistent behaviour in your complicated case which would be hard to debug. But I think, if you know your dataset boundaries, setting `datasource.minIndex` and `datasource.maxIndex` to appropriate values on the ui-scroll initialization might stabilize a consistency of scroll bar params.

Comment: @dhlit i tried with `datasource.minIndex` & `datasource.maxIndex` but it doesn't seems to fix the situation also the two scrolls are not fully sync. Somehow the the table which is being scrolled moves faster than the other and scroll positions are different even after first few scrolls. Any help would be highly appreciated..